# What is "mailto:someone@example.com" in following HTML form example?

Tags: html, email, forms, mailto, email-client

I am learning HTML from **w3schools HTML Tutorial - The Best in Class Tutorial**

I come across one HTML form example which sends an email.

Please note that currently neither do I nor w3schools is going for server side input processing, so you also don't think about server side processing while considering my question.

Below is the code of HTML example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Send e-mail to someone@example.com:</h2>

<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Normally I see a .php or .asp filename in action attribute of a form but in above example it's `mailto:someone@example.com`.

I want to know what is it and why they have not used a .php or .asp file-name as they normally do?

Please someone explain me.

Thank You.

Comment: did you at least google about `mailto` ?

Comment: mailto: links typically open your native email program

Comment: You already have given the answer yourself: "Please note that currently neither do I nor w3schools is going for server side input processing" - so you can't use php or asp as they *require a server*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically giving the users browser the job of handling the `mailto` request. The browser usually starts the users `mail client` and fills in the fields according to the input of your form.

Comment: By 'Mail Client' do you mean Microsoft Outlook, Thunderbird, etc.?

Comment: Yes thats what I meant.

Comment: So, is "mailto"  also an HTTP service/method like GET and POST?

Comment: No, Mailto is a type of HTML link that activates the default mail client on the computer for sending an e-mail.
The web browser requires a default e-mail client software installed on his computer in order to activate the e-mail client.
If you have Microsoft Outlook, for example as your default mail client, pressing a mailto link will open a new mail window.